# Pass delegate together with parameter to a function

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates

I want enqueue a list of tasks and then perform on certain event. Code:

```
internal class MyClass
{
    private Queue<Task> m_taskQueue;

    protected MyClass()
    {
        m_taskQueue = new Queue<Task>();
    }

    public delegate bool Task(object[] args);

    public void EnqueueTask(Task task)
    {
        m_taskQueue.Enqueue(task);
    }

    public virtual bool Save()
    {
        // save by processing work queue
        while (m_taskQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            var task = m_taskQueue.Dequeue(); 
            var workItemResult = task.Invoke();

            if (!workItemResult) 
            {
                // give up on a failure
                m_taskQueue.Clear();
                return false;
            }                
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Each delegate task may have their own list of parameters: Task(object[] args). My question is how to pass the parameter to each task for the task queue?

Comment: Pass which parameter? You haven't really explained what you're trying to do...

Comment: @Jon, clarified in the question.

Comment: Not really... you've said that each task will have its own list of parameters, but you haven't said anything about where you expect to get that data from.

Comment: @Jon, supposed to be in EnqueueTask(), so a caller Enqueue a task with it's parameters for later processing.

Comment: That's where having appropriate sample code would be useful... presumably it should be another parameter then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, now we have a bit more information, it sounds like your `EnqueueTask` method should actually look like this:

```
public void EnqueueTask(Task task, object[] values)
```

Right?

For *starters* I would avoid using the name `Task`, which is already part of the core of .NET 4 and will become *very* prominent in .NET 5. As Joshua said, you've basically got a `Func<object[], bool>`.

Next, you *could* keep two lists - one for the delegates and one for the values, but it's easier just to keep a `Queue<Func<bool>>` like this:

```
private readonly Queue<Func<bool>> taskQueue = new Queue<Func<bool>>();


public void EnqueueTask(Task task, object[] values)
{
    taskQueue.Enqueue(() => task(values));
}
```

Then the rest of your code will actually work "as is". The lambda expression there will capture `values` and `task`, so when you invoke the `Func<bool>`, it will supply those values to the original delegate.

Comment: Yes, that was my intention. This is exactly what I need. One minor, I think Add() need to be replaced by Queue().

Answer (score 1):

Provided understanding your question correctly you just pass the information like a normal call. Have you considered using Func? You can just pass arguments to the `Task.Invoke` i.e. `Task.Invoke([arguments here as a *single* object array])`.

```
object[] arguments = null; // assign arguments to something
var workItemResult = task.Invoke(arguments);
```

Below is an example with the Func type.

```
internal class MyClass
    {
        private Queue<Func<object[], bool>> m_taskQueue;

        protected MyClass()
        {
            m_taskQueue = new Queue<Func<object[], bool>>();
        }



        public void EnqueueTask(Func<object[], bool> task)
        {
            m_taskQueue.Enqueue(task);
        }

        public virtual bool Save()
        {
            object[] arguments = null; // assign arguments to something
            // save by processing work queue
            while (m_taskQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                var task = m_taskQueue.Dequeue();
                var workItemResult = task(arguments);

                if (!workItemResult)
                {
                    // give up on a failure
                    m_taskQueue.Clear();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: my question is keeping the parameters at Enqueue() from the caller and then process these tasks together with the passed parameters.

Comment: Parameters are part of the signature of the function you don't pass a parameter to a function. Arguments are the actual "values" you pass when you call a function. Do you mean you want to save the arguments and call together? If that's the case just put your Delegate and an object[] array together in a new class and then Enqueue an instance of that new class, then after Dequeue invoke the delegate with the object[] in the class.

Comment: Yes, argument is what I meant. Your suggestion is what I saw in other samples. Wondering if there are other ways.

Comment: Whoever +1d me, I'd recommend +1 Jon's answer. His is more elegant using the closures.